# Why the first click on the button doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, button, click, display

jsfiddle.net/coder344/13nmx5kj/1/
When I click on the button it doesn't work properly (with display:block)

Comment: Please add your code as text ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)) to the question. See [ask].

Comment: What does not work for you? When I click this text appears and disappears. maybe you want to achieve something else? Pls insert your code to question and make it more precise :)

Comment: yes, it works, BUT only after second click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your click is going under else part.

display: none; is commonly used with JavaScript to hide and show elements without deleting and recreating them. The  element uses display: none; as default.
You can achieve the desired out put by putting none under "" in your style sheet.

Refer the fiddle.

```js
function myFunction() {
let x = document.getElementById("div");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
alert(1);
    x.style.display = "block";
}
  else {
  alert(2);
      x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "myFunction()">Click Me</button>
<div id="div">some text here</div>
```